# How do I make one table column to be auto size according to its content and second column to fill all the spare space?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a web application in HTML5, where I have a table with two columns I want the first column width to be auto size so it's fit the content inside the column and the second column width to fill all the spare space

I tried the following:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td style="display: inline-block">
        <div id="list">
            <table>
               ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="canvas">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But the second column always takes more width space than it should which cause the first column table rows to be multiline instead of one line.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The first column's contents become multi-line because the only auto-size mode available is one that tries to shrink the column as much as possible. If you don't want the contents to wrap, specify this explicitly using `white-space: nowrap`.

```css
.t1, .t2 { border-collapse: collapse; }
.t1 > tbody > tr > td { border: 1px solid red; }
.t2 > tbody > tr > td { border: 1px solid blue; }

.t3 td { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
Example 1:
<table style="width: 100%;" class=t1>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="list">
            <table class=t2>
                <tr><td>Thingy stuff</td><td>foo bar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Thingy stuff</td><td>foo bar</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="canvas">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>
Example 2:
    
<table style="width: 100%;" class=t1>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="list">
            <table class="t2 t3">
                <tr><td>Thingy stuff</td><td>foo bar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Thingy stuff</td><td>foo bar</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="canvas">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

No need to use JavaScript, and no need to set the right-hand cell to a specific width tailored for specific left-hand cell content.

Comment: Lovely. very clean solution.

Comment: Problem I had with this solution is that, the columns grow like anything when the content is lengthy. So, I had added following...

1. Wrapped content inside a div
2. Added max width for the above div with following CSS.

`td > div {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: ${getRem(300)};
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}`

Answer (score 3):

The solution is pretty simple thanks to Iaasch suggestion to use jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#left').css('width', $('#places-table').width());
    });

    <table style="width: 100%;"> 
    <tr>     
        <td id="left">         
            <div id="list">     
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ...
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>     
        </td>     
        <td style="width: auto;">         
            <div id="canvas">         
            </div>     
        </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set a `td` to `width:100%;`, it means 100% of the `tr`. So, it will be the entire row. Try making the right `td` like `width:75%;`.

Comment: This is simply false; sorry. Example proving that it won't necessarily be the entire row: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cbxed/1/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is your friend.

```
<table style="width: 100%;"> 
    <tr>     
        <td id="left" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">         
            <div id="list">     
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ...
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>     
        </td>     
        <td style="width: auto;">         
            <div id="canvas">         
            </div>     
        </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

and where you have your scripts add this:

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#left').css('width', $('#list').text().length * 7);
          })
```

Comment: Why are you multiply text length by 7? And how will this handle someone who has a larger font in their browser?

Comment: Arbitrary magic number to accomodate the width of the string. It doesn't account for larger fonts, kerning, etc. Shahaf's solution  below will probably account for that much better.